# jQuery- Add undo button for input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added an undo button for text input. when i click on undo, change event fires before click event.

Is there a way to fire click event before change? because i'd like to undo the text inside the input text then call the save method.

```js
$('.btnUndo').click(function () {
  console.log("undo clicked.")
  var input = $(this).closest('.txtUndoable').find('input');
        $(input).val($(input).attr('data-old-value'));
  });

$('.txtUndoable').change(function () {
  console.log("Save method")

     // Save method 
 })
```

```css
.txtUndoable {
    position: relative;
  width:150px;
}

    .txtUndoable .fa {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        /*pointer-events: none;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#26A8FF;
    }

.txtUndoable {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="txtUndoable">
   <i class="btnUndo fa fa-undo"></i>
   <input class="form-control" value="name" data-old-value="name">
</div>
```

Comment: How'd you like " to click event for undo button fires before change event"? Events are fired on user actions so mostly it is system behavior. What is the question?

Comment: @moshen _"but change event fires before click event."_ What action is performed at `change` event? `js` at post appears to return expected results? Note, `html` set `id` as `txtUndoable` at 

    `<div id="txtUndoable">`

though `javascript` references `txtUndoable` as a `className`

    `$('.txtUndoable')`

Comment: How would `click` event be called where `i` element does not appear to have text at `html`?

Comment: i've updated the question. that should be better now.    @guest271314 i fixed that one, sorry it was a mistake.

Comment: @mohsen _"when i click on undo, change event fires before click event."_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 i've added stack snippets.

Answer (score 0):

`js` at Question appears to return expected results? Not certain how `.btnUndo` can be clicked where element does not contain text?

You can utilize `.off()` at `click` handler, then reattach `change` event after `input` value changed. Note, `html` set `id` as `txtUndoable` at

```
<div id="txtUndoable">
```

though `javascript` references `txtUndoable` as a `className`

```
$('.txtUndoable')
```

```js
function changeHandler() {
  console.log("changeHandler")
    // Save method 
}

var txtUndoable = $(".txtUndoable");

$(function() {
  $(".btnUndo").click(function() {
    txtUndoable.off("change");
    var input = $(this).closest(".txtUndoable").find("input");
    input.val(input.attr("data-old-value"));
    txtUndoable.on("change", "input", changeHandler);
  });

  txtUndoable.change(changeHandler);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="txtUndoable">
  <i class="btnUndo fa fa-undo">Undo</i>
  <input class="form-control" value="" data-old-value="abc">
</div>
```

Comment: @moshen Does `javascript` at post return expected results?